# Why are my domain and username being prepended to stored procedures I create?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, every time I write a stored procedure such as `ThisIsAStoredProcedure`, it ends up showing in the list of stored procedures as `COMPANYDOMAIN\MYUSERNAME.ThisIsAStoredProcedure`.

I'd like it to be `dbo.ThisIsAStoredProcedure` instead.

I've tried right clicking and renaming, but this doesn't work.

I have three concerns:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I change the existing stored procedures with my domain\username prefix to `dbo.procedurename`?
3. How can I change the configuration to name procedures `dbo.procedurename` by default?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If you didn't explicitly set it, then objects created by you will be created under the default schema for your user. In SSMS, look in:
   Database -> Security -> Users -> `<you>` -> Properties -> General -> Default schema
2. `ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER [COMPANYDOMAIN\MYUSERNAME].ThisIsAStoredProcedure;`
3. Change the setting you looked at in 1.

Of course, you may not have permission to do 2 or 3, in which case it's a question for the person that does have permission.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I don't do a lot of admin or security work, so it would've taken me forever to find this setting. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

On the right hand upper side of Sql Server Management Studio, there is an option when creating the table, to select the schema. I recreated the database and selected the proper schema